# Editing Docker content

Tags: docker, development-environment

I am looking at Docker to share and contain applications, after reading several articles on the subject I can't figure out what the steps would be to use a Docker container for actual development. Is that even acceptable?

My thought process goes like this

- Create DockerFile
- Share DockerFile
- User A and B download DockerFile
- User A and B install images
- User A and B are able to make changes to their local containers
- User A and B submit changes

The way I have been reading different articles Docker is only to share applications but not for continuous development the way I am thinking, the closest I can think of on what I am explaining above is to make changes outside the containers and commit to a repo outside the containers, then the containers will update the local repo and re-run the application internally but you would never develop on the container itself.

Comment: It is also possible to upload the said docker container to a docker repository, including the public docker hub. That way User B does not have to build- the container, they just download and start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using docker for development process is not only possible, but handy and convenient in my opinion.

What you might have missed during your study of the docker ecosystem is the concept of `volumes`.

With volumes you can bind mount a directory of your host (the developer computer) into the container.

You may want to use volumes to share application data folder, making it possible for the devs to work on their local copies normally, but have their application served by a docker container.

A link to get started: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/